# PHOTO cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the example Android code given here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html
to grab the thumbnails of contacts (the top example code).

However, I can't get beyond the error:
'PHOTO cannot be resolved or is not a field'

This is the code:

```
public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) 
    {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
             new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have the following imports listed at the top of the class file:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.Object;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I am sure that it is something really simple, like a missing import, but I am at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: code seems fine. what is the device/emulator OS version you are testing on??

Comment: This is showing up as an error in Eclipse, so I can't run it yet.

Comment: In fact, I have tracked it down to an API level issue. It will stop reporting an error when the project is set to target Android 3 (API 11). It appears that the claim on the Android site that ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo has been available since API level 5 is untrue. Targeting Android 3 is no use to me unfortunately.

Comment: yes. see my answer. you can use API 5. most of the android devices are well over Android 2.1(API 7) now

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't work until the API level is set to 11 (Android 3) which few devices have yet. I was targeting it at API level 7 anyway. Even setting it at Android 2.3.3 - API 10 - still reports the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your target in eclipse should be >= API 5. make sure you target is Android 2.0 or above because the `android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo` requires API 5 or greater

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
```

instead of

```
import android.provider.Contacts;
```